# How to efficiently right this query?

Tags: mysql

I have a query in a stored procedure like this:

```
"DELETE FROM tbl1 
 WHERE id1
  NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tbl2)
  AND id2 
    NOT IN(SELECT id FROM tbl2);"
```

Now I want to know how can I use the inner SELECT just one time? Can it be effective on execution's speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from tbl1 
where not exists (select 1 from tbl2 where id in (tbl1.id1,tbl1.id2))
```